# Concatenate arrays with stack numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
import numpy as np

t = np.arange(3)

for i in range(5):
  a = np.arange(3)
  np.stack((t, a))

print(t)
```

output = [0 1 2]

Please some help to contatenate arrays in a loop for, ty!

Comment: `np.stack` is not running in place… Also we have no clue of the expected output

Comment: why? collect the values in a list, and do just one stack.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```py
import numpy as np

t = np.arange(3)

for i in range(5):
  a = np.arange(3)
  t = np.concatenate((t, a))

print(t)
```

Output:

```
[0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: ty alor my friend, works! –

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

t = np.arange(3)

for i in range(5):
  a = np.arange(3)
  t = np.vstack((t, a))

print(t)
```

Output:

```
[[0 1 2]
 [0 1 2]
 [0 1 2]
 [0 1 2]
 [0 1 2]
 [0 1 2]]
```

Comment: repeated `vstack` is not a good idea,  Too much copying.

Comment: ty alor my friend, works! –

Answer (score 0):

**Note** that **avoidung for-loops** makes the same task

1. with `nx,ny = 5,5`  **5 times faster**
2. with `nx,ny = 50,50`  **31    times faster**
3. with `nx,ny = 500,500`  **57    times faster**

Here the code:

```
import numpy as np
nx = 500; ny = 500

def f0():
    t = np.arange(ny)
    for i in range(nx):
      a = np.arange(ny)
      t = np.vstack((t, a))   
    return t


def f1():
    o = np.ones(nx, dtype=int)
    t = np.arange(ny)
    return np.outer(o,t)  # the outer product between 2 vectors

%timeit y0 = f0()
13.2 ms ± 1.35 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)


%timeit y1 = f1()
229 µs ± 1.95 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: ty alor my friend, works!